# JavaFx 2.2: On the first time run my application after setup, very slow to show the main page, why?

Tags: javafx, startup

My project is a OSGI based C/S architecture, my setup tool is InnoSetup.
On the first time run my application after setup(or after computer reboot), it's very slow to show the main page(about 50 seconds), but on the second/third/... time, it would be very fast(about 6 seconds).

I wrote some logs on startup and find OSGI framework didn't slower the startup.

I think the reason should be: When first run my app after setup(or after computer reboot), javaFX would invoke some dll or libs in the Windows OS to draw the page, and javaFX would cache this so the next startup would be quicker. Is that right?

How can improve the first startup(or after computer reboot) speed?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think thats normal because the server does compile the whole source code at runtime.